# Bug in Grid row_id as a limiting parameter?

Tags: grid

I'm getting some odd behaviour from my Grid field in the template (unless I'm misunderstanding the Grid docs). I have a custom Grid field used for placing images (columns are file, alt text and caption). In one of my channel entries I have three images set via this field. The following template code displays all three images, as expected:

```
{my_image_grid}
<figure>
    <img src="{my_image_grid:file}" alt="{my_image_grid:alt}">
    <figcaption>{my_image_grid:caption}</figcaption>
</figure>
{/my_image_grid}
```

And, also as expected, this code displays only the contents of the **first** row of the grid field:

```
{my_image_grid row_id="1"}
    <figure>
        <img src="{my_image_grid:file}" alt="{my_image_grid:alt}">
        <figcaption>{my_image_grid:caption}</figcaption>
    </figure>
{/my_image_grid}
```

However, when I try to display all rows *other than* row 1, with the following:

```
{my_image_grid row_id="not 1"}
    <figure>
        <img src="{my_image_grid:file}" alt="{my_image_grid:alt}">
        <figcaption>{my_image_grid:caption}</figcaption>
    </figure>
{/my_image_grid}
```

I get just the first row again. Just the first row is also displayed if I try to display a specific row other than 1:

```
{my_image_grid row_id="3"}
    <figure>
        <img src="{my_image_grid:file}" alt="{my_image_grid:alt}">
        <figcaption>{my_image_grid:caption}</figcaption>
    </figure>
{/my_image_grid}
```

Can anyone else verify this behaviour before I report it as a bug? Or am I doing something wrong (eg. misunderstanding how rows are ID-ed)? This is EE 2.7.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems row_id works on the database table ID, not on the row number.
Use the offset parameter and {gridfield:count} variable instead.

<del>In my opinion it's a bug, because if you only provide one row, the grid-parser will not take "not" into account somehow.

To circumvent this bug add a zero in front so that it 'thinks' it has multiple entries.

```
row_id="not 0|1"
```</del>

(ps. bug filed: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19852 )

Comment: Hmm. Adding the zero as you suggest seems to bypass the row_id parameter entirely, because now I'm getting all three rows again, not just rows 2 and 3 as I should. It definitely appears to be a bug, but it goes farther than just the 'not' part of the parameter, as demonstrated by the fact that row_id="3" doesn't work either (see the last code example in my original post). I'll add a comment to your bug report, GDmac, with some extra info from my own experiences.

Comment: i tested with row_id="3" and row_id="not 0|3" and all works. But if you do row_id="4", and only have 3 rows, it will show row 1. (adding to bug report)

Comment: I've editted the post, row_id is database related, not row number related.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think in that case that the database table ID should be easier to find -- it's pretty elusive as things stand.

Comment: you can use ```{if gridfield:count == 2 || gridfield:count == 3}``` or check if greater than ```{if gridfield:count > 2}```

Comment: Also you could use switchee which has regex support :-) {case value="#(2|4|5)#"} or thelike

Comment: Seems like Kevin at Ellis has issued a patch for the 'not' parameter not working properly. I think that the failure to display specific rows was not a bug in the code but an artefact of my using row numbers instead of row table IDs. Currently there is no easy way to get the table ID for a row from the CP but using {my_grid_fieldname:row_id} as a variable in the template will reveal it. As far as I can see this variable /is/ mentioned in the docs but only in passing (as art of the :next_row and prev_row variables). It should probably have an entry of its own since it's quite useful.

Comment: Here is the patch to get the 'not' exclusion parameter modifier working: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19852
 
It should be folded into the next version of EE.